# how to create PDF in java web application dynamically to show booked tickets details

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

when we book tickets online, after booking we get a mail containing a pdf file which is actually our ticket. the same thing i want to do with my javaweb application but i don't know how to create a pdf that can show details about ticket and it should be well designed means there should a header, a table containing passenger details etc. 
Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look in JasperReports.

Comment: Thanks. I got what i need